# Kahler differentials give a left Quillen functor

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, model-categories

Is there a reference for the fact that the functor of Kahler differentials is a left Quillen functor on the category of CDGA (over a field of characteristic $0$)?

Remark: I mean the model structure on the slice category $\textrm{CDGA}/B$ for some CDGA $B.$

Edit: the question was [cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439886/kahler-differentials-give-a-left-quillen-functor-reference-request) to MO

Comment: Appears to be answered on page 33 of: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.12699.pdf